# iOS keyboard moves position of DIVS

Tags: css, html

I have a mobile chatroom i'm using. Whenever I load it up in safari on an iphone. Clicking in the text area brings up the keyboard, which I want but the keyboard completely ruins the layout of the webpage. How do I fix this? Heres a link to the http://www.306radio.ca/mobile/chat/

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look, it looks like the issue you are having is coming from the `div#userContent` having a style of `float: left`, and the `div` above it having `position:absolute`. Those two seem to be causing the reflow you're experiencing.

I removed the `float` and removed the `positioning`, and that solved the reflow, but it looks like there could still be issues with JavaScript resizing the widths of things on the page.

Unfortunately, I don't have time to look into it, but this should fix the issue your question asked.

Keep digging in to CSS, and especially responsive design, and you might be able to solve this solution with less CSS and JS code.